# Search in submatrices

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty sure it's an easy question which I knew the answer of, but it just ran of my mind. So I am asking for help :) (no hate please)

So here is what I want to do.
Lets say the left box is from [0,0] to [2,2] and the right box is from [0,3] to [2,5].
And I am given the point [2,4] which is a value from the right box. How can I perform a comparison with the values only from the box?
For example if the value on [2,4] is 5, I want to check if there is another number 5 in the box?

Here is an example matrix too:

`int[][] matrix = {
                { 2, 0, 5, 0, 1, 7 },
                { 1, 3, 6, 4, 0, 5 },
                { 2, 0, 5, 9, 5, 7 },
        }`

[image: Matrix]

Comment: You have not shown what the logic is behind splitting your matrix into boxes, looks like you want to limit your search to those index values j >= 3 where your search space is [i][j] for i=0 i<matrix.length;

Comment: You build a for loop.  your matrix variable is an array of arrays, and you can treat it like that.  calling matrix[1][2] will give you an int value, but calling matrix[1] will give you the whole array of {1, 3, 6, 4, 0, 5}.  If you nest a for loop in a for loop you can loop through all three outer arrays and all of the values of the inner array.

Comment: plz clarify this statement "if the value on [2,4] is 5, I want to check if there is another number 5 in the box?"

Comment: Thank you Farlan, that should work for what I am trying to do.